# Create user session in rspec test

Tags: ruby, session, post, rspec

i would be create a user session in a rspec test. But i can´t create, because it gives the following error:

[stacktrace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBesy.png)

My Test Code:

```
describe Api::V1::CustomersController, type: :controller do
 describe '#create' do
  before(:each) do
    user = FactoryGirl.create(:superuser)
    UserSession.create(user)

    session[:user_id] = user.id
  end

  it 'test the create route' do
    json_data = '{"data":{"attributes":{"name":"theo test","website":"","iban":"","bic":"","bill_email":"",
              "patient_number_prefix":""},"type":""}}'

    post 'create', body: json_data, session: session, format: :json

    json = JSON.parse(response.body)

    expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)
    expect(json['data']).not_to be_nil
  end
 end
end
```

The UserSession:

```
class UserSession < Authlogic::Session::Base
 self.last_request_at_threshold = 10.minutes

 # Convenience method for the persistence_token
 public def persistence_token
   record&.persistence_token
 end
end
```

The CustomerController:

```
class Api::V1::CustomersController < ApplicationController
  public def create
    action(Customer::Create)
    .otherwise('customer_create_error', 401)
    .then_render(Customer::Representer::Out::Default)
  end
end
```

My session is in `config/initializers/session_store.rb` defined:

```
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_example_session'
```

operations.rb

```
module Webapp::ControllerHelper::Operations
 public def action(op = nil, effective_params = params)
  return if op.nil?

  # Call the operation
  result = op.(effective_params,
   'current_user' => current_user,
   'document' => request.raw_post)

  # Build and return the OperationResult object
  Webapp::OperationResult.new(result, method(:render))
 end
end
```

Anybody a idea why?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. How is your controller defined? How does you application handle authentication? How is `session` defined? There is not enough information in your question for us to answer it.

Comment: I once added more information

Comment: .....And what is `action(Customer::Create)`? Please provide a **complete** example.

Comment: so.............

Comment: So it looks like we're going down a dark rabbit hole of service objects. And I still have no idea what lies at the bottom.

Comment: My *guess* - and this is only a guess, because I still don't know the full picture here - is that eventually you're calling some method on `Customer::Create`, which fails *for some reason*; possibly unrelated to authentication errors. Like, maybe it's actually a validation error. And you're returning `401 unauthorized` for **all** errors, rather than a more helpful `400`, or `404`, or `422`, or whatever else it might be.

Comment: Yes sry, it is a company software and I can't show you everything.

Comment: If you can't find a way to provide a [mcve] (by stripping out/redacting anything 'company confidential'), then we won't be able to help much, sorry. I can only make vague predictions about the possible cause.

Comment: Yes, you got that right. I'm trying to. In the examples shown so far I have had to take a lot out of it.

Comment: You don't have to provide your company software code. Create a small app which can reproduce the problem. Provide us with the code of that small app.